# XHTML with WebKit

Tags: gtk, vala

I am working on an ebook application with WebKit 3 (webkitgtk-3.0) on Elementaty OS Freya. epubs which have html display fine, however the new epub 3 with XHTML comes garbled with multi columns instead of paragraphs. I have attached screen shots of both. changing the mime type to "application/xhtml+xml" also does not resolve the XHTML content. Code at launchpad [image: here].

Appreciate any guidance on how to fix this.

Comment: I rewrote the code with my own parser for epub and using webkit2gtk-4.0 and the problem seems to be resolved.

Comment: If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code with my own parser for epub and using webkit2gtk-4.0 and the problem seems to be resolved.
https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm